# Maximum dy value for XSSFClientAnchor

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Using Apache-POI, I'm trying to insert an image in an Excel sheet with an upper-left corner halfway a row with a large font (Calibri-32).
Using the well-known formulas, I figured out that that the `dy1` value within the `XSSFClientAnchor` should be something like 260,000.
However, when opening the Excel file, I get an error saying the contents is illeggible.
Accepting the warning, **the image is shown correctly anyway**.

After some tests, I figured out that the maximum value of the dy, without getting an error from Excel, appears to be `190,500`.
The font I use, results in a row height of 55 pixels.
Halfway the row is therefore `0.5*55*Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL=261,938`.

The same problem occurs when using a smaller font but making the image start near the end of the row.
In all cases, I get an error if the `dy1` has a value greater than 190500.

Is there anyone who's got a clue?

UPDATE:
I extracted the `xml` from the xlsx file and I noticed a negative `cy` value somewhere. I'm not really familar with the xlsx contents but I hope it's useful for somebody:

```
<xdr:wsDr xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
  <xdr:twoCellAnchor editAs="oneCell">
    <xdr:from>
      <xdr:col>2</xdr:col>
      <xdr:colOff>147637</xdr:colOff>
      <xdr:row>0</xdr:row>
      <xdr:rowOff>261937</xdr:rowOff>
    </xdr:from>
    <xdr:to>
      <xdr:col>5</xdr:col>
      <xdr:colOff>2309812</xdr:colOff>
      <xdr:row>13</xdr:row>
      <xdr:rowOff>14287</xdr:rowOff>
    </xdr:to>
    <xdr:pic>
      <xdr:nvPicPr>
        <xdr:cNvPr id="1" name="Picture 1" descr="Picture"/>
        <xdr:cNvPicPr>
          <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="true"/>
        </xdr:cNvPicPr>
      </xdr:nvPicPr>
      <xdr:blipFill>
        <a:blip r:embed="rId1"/>
        <a:stretch>
          <a:fillRect/>
        </a:stretch>
      </xdr:blipFill>
      <xdr:spPr>
        <a:xfrm>
          <a:off x="147637" y="261937"/>
          <a:ext cx="195263" cy="-71437"/>
        </a:xfrm>
        <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
          <a:avLst/>
        </a:prstGeom>
      </xdr:spPr>
    </xdr:pic>
    <xdr:clientData/>
  </xdr:twoCellAnchor>
</xdr:wsDr>
```

UPDATE 2:
The following code shows the error. It occurs if dy1 is greater than 190500 AND row2 equals row1+1

```
/**********************************************************************************************************************
 * Package specification
 *********************************************************************************************************************/
package test;

/**********************************************************************************************************************
 * Import definitions
 *********************************************************************************************************************/
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

/**********************************************************************************************************************
 * This class implements a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example for the problem of the maximum dy value for the
 * {@link XSSFClientAnchor}.
 *********************************************************************************************************************/
public class TestPictureOffset
{
  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This constants represents the name of the file with the picture to import within the sheet.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private static final String FILENAME_PICTURE = "./excel.png";

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * These constants represents the width and height of the big cell within the sheet.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private static final short BIG_CELL_COLUMN_WIDTH_IN_PIXELS = 317;
  private static final short BIG_CELL_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_PIXELS = 56;

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This constants represents the default height of a cell within the sheet.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private static final short DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_PIXELS = 20;

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method places the specified picture on the sheet.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private static void setPicture(int        picture_index,
                                 SXSSFSheet sheet)
  {
    // -----------------
    // Initialize anchor
    // -----------------
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor;
    anchor = (XSSFClientAnchor)sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper().createClientAnchor();
    anchor.setAnchorType(XSSFClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

    // -----------------------------
    // Set position
    // THIS IS WHERE THE FUN HAPPENS
    // -----------------------------
    anchor.setCol1(1);
    anchor.setRow1(0);
    anchor.setDx1((int)(0.5 * BIG_CELL_COLUMN_WIDTH_IN_PIXELS * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL));
    anchor.setDy1((int)(0.4 * BIG_CELL_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_PIXELS * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL));
    anchor.setCol2(anchor.getCol1() + 1);
    anchor.setRow2(anchor.getRow1() + 1);   // Fails if dy1 > 190500
    //anchor.setRow2(anchor.getRow1() + 2); // OK independently from dy1
    anchor.setDx2(0);
    anchor.setDy2(0);

    // ----------------------
    // Show some measurements
    // ----------------------
    System.out.println("Got dy1: " + anchor.getDy1());
    System.out.println("Maximum dy in default cell: " + (DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_PIXELS * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL));

    // ----------------
    // Draw the picture
    // ----------------
    sheet.createDrawingPatriarch().createPicture(anchor, picture_index);

  } // setPicture

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method runs the application.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private static void run()
    throws Exception
  {
    // ---------------
    // Create workbook
    // ---------------
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook;
    workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);

    // ------------
    // Create sheet
    // ------------
    SXSSFSheet sheet;
    sheet = workbook.createSheet("TestSheet");
    sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();

    // --------------------------
    // Create style with big font
    // --------------------------
    Font          font;
    XSSFCellStyle style;
    font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)32);
    style = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFont(font);

    // -------------------
    // Write something big
    // -------------------
    SXSSFRow  row;
    SXSSFCell cell;
    row = sheet.createRow(0);
    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    cell.setCellValue("Hello everybody");

    // -----------------------
    // Auto resize this column
    // -----------------------
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

    // ------------
    // Load picture
    // ------------
    InputStream input_stream;
    byte[]      bytes;
    input_stream = new FileInputStream(FILENAME_PICTURE);
    bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input_stream);
    input_stream.close();

    // ---------------
    // Add to workbook
    // ---------------
    int picture_index;
    picture_index = workbook.addPicture(bytes, SXSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);

    // -------------------------
    // Position picture in sheet
    // -------------------------
    setPicture(picture_index, sheet);

    // -------------
    // Save workbook
    // -------------
    File             output_file;
    FileOutputStream output_stream;
    output_file = new File("testxls.xlsx");
    output_stream = new FileOutputStream(output_file);
    workbook.write(output_stream);
    output_stream.close();
    workbook.close();

    // -------
    // Open it
    // -------
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(output_file);

  } // run

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   *                                                M A I N
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      run();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }

  } // main

} // class TestPictureOffset
```

Comment: Instead of much prosa you should show the code which produces this `xl\drawings\drawing1.xml`. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The negative `cy` has nothing to do with the anchor which is in first part of the `XML` and looks good for me. So the question is where the negative `cy` is coming from. So the code is needed.

Comment: It's gonna take me a while to create this minimal, complete and verifiable example, but I'll be back ASAP.

Comment: Creating the famous example, I found out what the problem was: I initially set the lower right corner to the beginning of the successive row/column (col2=col1+1; row2=row1+1;dx2=0;dy2=0). Than, using the SXSSFPicture in order to obtain the original size of the image, I adjust the lower corner. The problem is solved setting the initial lower right corner with col2=col1+1, row2=row1+1 and dx2/dy2 equal to dx1/dy1.

Comment: "Creating the famous example, I found out what the problem was": Well that's exactly one of the advantages of creating a simple example of the problem: Because of the need simplifying mostly one will find the reason of the problem oneself ;-).

Comment: I updated the question, inserting an example of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we need determining where the negative `cy` may comes from.

At first: You should not using constants for BIG_CELL_COLUMN_WIDTH_IN_PIXELS and BIG_CELL_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_PIXELS. Instead do the same as apache poi does and use `sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels` and [ImageUtils.getRowHeightInPixels](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/ImageUtils.html#getRowHeightInPixels-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet-int-) to calculate width and height.

And you need set row height according to the fonts height. Else the row remains in default height until `Excel` is rendering  the sheet in view. And in default row height, the `dy1` is outside the row if greater than 190500. So it would not be a valid `dy1` for this row.

There is [private CTTransform2D createXfrm(XSSFClientAnchor anchor)](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFDrawing.java?view=markup#l517) in `XSSFDrawing.java` which calculates the `xfrm` containing the `cy`. There you can see, that a negative `cy` only occurs if `height + anchor.getDy2()` is lower than `anchor.getDy1()`.

Using `XSSF` this would be enough. But using `SXSSF` the calculation of the row height in `private CTTransform2D createXfrm(XSSFClientAnchor anchor)` using `ImageUtils.getRowHeightInPixels(sheet, row)` seems to be wrong. I suspect this is because row height is not known already in the sheet because of the streaming manner. So we need a workaround. Set default row height that big as needed for the big font, set the picture then and reset the default row height after that.

The following works for me:

```
/**********************************************************************************************************************
 * Import definitions
 *********************************************************************************************************************/
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.ImageUtils;

/**********************************************************************************************************************
 * This class implements a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example for the problem of the maximum dy value for the
 * {@link XSSFClientAnchor}.
 *********************************************************************************************************************/
public class TestPictureOffset
{
  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This constants represents the name of the file with the picture to import within the sheet.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private static final String FILENAME_PICTURE = "./excel.png";

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * These constants represents the width and height of the big cell within the sheet.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  // Don't do that. Instead do the same as apache poi does and use
  // sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels and
  // ImageUtils.getRowHeightInPixels to calculate width and height

  private static final short BIG_CELL_COLUMN_WIDTH_IN_PIXELS = 317;
  private static final short BIG_CELL_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_PIXELS = 56;

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This constants represents the default height of a cell within the sheet.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private static final short DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_PIXELS = 20;

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method places the specified picture on the sheet.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private static void setPicture(int        picture_index,
                                 Sheet sheet)
  {
    // -----------------
    // Initialize anchor
    // -----------------
    ClientAnchor anchor;
    anchor = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper().createClientAnchor();
    anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

    // -----------------------------
    // Set position
    // THIS IS WHERE THE FUN HAPPENS
    // -----------------------------
    anchor.setCol1(1);
    anchor.setRow1(0);
    //anchor.setDx1((int)(0.5 * BIG_CELL_COLUMN_WIDTH_IN_PIXELS * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL));
    //anchor.setDy1((int)(0.4 * BIG_CELL_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_PIXELS * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL));
    anchor.setDx1((int)(0.5 * sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(1) * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL));
    anchor.setDy1((int)(0.4 * ImageUtils.getRowHeightInPixels(sheet, 0) * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL));
    anchor.setCol2(anchor.getCol1() + 1);
    anchor.setRow2(anchor.getRow1() + 1);   // Fails if dy1 > 190500
    //anchor.setRow2(anchor.getRow1() + 2); // OK independently from dy1
    anchor.setDx2(0);
    anchor.setDy2(0);

    // ----------------------
    // Show some measurements
    // ----------------------
    System.out.println("Got dy1: " + anchor.getDy1());
    System.out.println("Maximum dy in default cell: " + (DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT_IN_PIXELS * Units.EMU_PER_PIXEL));

    // ----------------
    // Draw the picture
    // ----------------
    sheet.createDrawingPatriarch().createPicture(anchor, picture_index);

  } // setPicture

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   * This method runs the application.
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  private static void run()
    throws Exception
  {
    // ---------------
    // Create workbook
    // ---------------
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook;
    workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
    workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);

    // ------------
    // Create sheet
    // ------------
    SXSSFSheet sheet;
    sheet = workbook.createSheet("TestSheet");
    sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();

    // --------------------------
    // Create style with big font
    // --------------------------
    Font          font;
    CellStyle style;
    font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)32);
    style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFont(font);

    // -------------------
    // Write something big
    // -------------------
    SXSSFRow  row;
    SXSSFCell cell;
    row = sheet.createRow(0);
    cell = row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
    cell.setCellValue("Hello everybody");

    // -----------------------
    // Set row heigth according to the fonts height
    // -----------------------
    row.setHeightInPoints(workbook.getFontAt(style.getFontIndex()).getFontHeightInPoints()*1.275f);

    // -----------------------
    // Auto resize this column
    // -----------------------
    sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

    // ------------
    // Load picture
    // ------------
    InputStream input_stream;
    byte[]      bytes;
    input_stream = new FileInputStream(FILENAME_PICTURE);
    bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input_stream);
    input_stream.close();

    // ---------------
    // Add to workbook
    // ---------------
    int picture_index;
    picture_index = workbook.addPicture(bytes, SXSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);

    // -------------------------
    // Position picture in sheet
    // -------------------------
    // Workaround for SXSSFSheet which has not the correct row height in
    // private CTTransform2D createXfrm(XSSFClientAnchor anchor) 
    // because of the streaming manner.
    // So set default row height that big:
    sheet.setDefaultRowHeight(sheet.getRow(0).getHeight());
    // set the picture then:
    setPicture(picture_index, sheet);
    // and reset the default row height after that:
    sheet.setDefaultRowHeight((short)(15*20));

    // -------------
    // Save workbook
    // -------------
    File             output_file;
    FileOutputStream output_stream;
    output_file = new File("testxls.xlsx");
    output_stream = new FileOutputStream(output_file);
    workbook.write(output_stream);
    output_stream.close();
    workbook.close();

    workbook.dispose();

    // -------
    // Open it
    // -------
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(output_file);

  } // run

  /********************************************************************************************************************
   *                                                M A I N
   *******************************************************************************************************************/
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      run();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }

  } // main

} // class TestPictureOffset
```

Comment: I used the constants only within the example. The actual source code calculates the width and height, taking into account that a single row may contain different fonts and that the default font may differ from Calibri-11. Anyway, I now temporarily set the default row height to the height of the first row that will be (partially) covered by the picture, then add the picture and finally restore the default row height. Works great. Thanks.